# Is there a way to build RISC-V GNU tools for multiple architectures?

Tags: gcc, gnu, riscv

I cloned and built the RISC-V GNU toolchain. I built the Newlib version for RV32I architecture(--with-arch=rv32i). However, I also need to have the RV32IM architecture build. Problem is, if I build the compiler for **RV32IM**, and compile my RISC-V code for **RV32I**, the compiler emulates multiply/divide operations for the RV32I architecture but still uses `mul` instrucions. I think this happens because there are `mul` instructions in the libgcc.a file, because that's the architecture it was built for. This is why I desire to have two seperate builds, i.e. **RV32I** and **RV32IM**.

Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess a `multilib` version could be built. [riscv-none-embed-gcc-xpack](https://github.com/xpack-dev-tools/riscv-none-embed-gcc-xpack) is such a multilib version without `libgloss`, but I haven't delved into the details of implementation. Hope it'll help.